# How to query couchbase for a document using the rest API

Tags: couchbase

I know how to do it for views, for example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8092/<my_bucket>/_design/all/_view/all?full_set=true&key=<my_document_key>&connection_timeout=60000
```

And I tried:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8091/contacts/hello
```

(after creating via the UI a document with the key hello).
And the response was "Not Found."

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 3):

There is no REST API for retrieving documents by key. You can either write your own thin service layer that uses the client SDK internally, or as of Couchbase 4.0, use the N1QL REST API to get the document through a query by key:

```
SELECT * FROM bucket USE KEYS [docId];
```

You can read about using the N1QL service endpoint here: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/index.html

(Edit: Changed N1QL syntax to actually work. Thanks Gerald.)

Answer (score 1):

In following way we can access couchbase document

**Syntax:** 
hostname:8091/pools/default/buckets/{bucketname}/docs/{docid}

> http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/Aggregation/docs/AvgSumAssuredByProduct

**Where**

`To access bucket related, use api:` http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/

`Bucket Name:` Aggregation

`docid :` AvgSumAssuredByProduct

Comment: even if you can access the document somehow, that doesn't mean you should. Couchbase is not designed to offer a rest endpoint as de SDK is "stateful"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it for development purpose then you can use CLI or admin console (UI).

In production you should ALWAYS use language specific client SDK. Couchbase SDKs are intelligent as they have details about cluster map. `Client knows before hand about which node should be used for CRUD operation.`